# Assignment before declaration in golang net/http/server.go

Tags: go

I was going to code in golang net/http/server.go and found following code at https://github.com/golang/go/blob/96745b980cfde139e8611772e2bc0c59a8e6cdf7/src/net/http/server.go#L2208

```
// DefaultServeMux is the default ServeMux used by Serve.
var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux

var defaultServeMux ServeMux
```

Here we see that defaultServerMux pointer is assigned before it is declared in next line. I have not tried building it myself but it from a release commit. How is it working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language spec explains variable initialization as:

> ...a package-level variable is considered ready for initialization if it is not yet initialized and either has no initialization expression or its initialization expression has no dependencies on uninitialized variables. Initialization proceeds by repeatedly initializing the next package-level variable that is earliest in declaration order and ready for initialization, until there are no variables ready for initialization.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization

So, all variables with no dependencies are initialized first, then the variables depending on initialized variables, and so on.